# Как сделать сортировку по нескольким условиям?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть такая задача. Вывыести таблицу с определенной сортировкой.

1) По дате создания - (есть поле `date_create` по нему делаю)

```
ORDER BY date_create DESC
```

2) Актуальные ли объявления - (есть поле `archive`, где 0 это актуальные 1 нет)

3) Дата отправки не позднее сегодняшнего - (есть поле `discharge_date` который хранит дату отправки)

так вот, как получить все в одном запросе сначало записи 
1) Свежие по дате объявления, Актуальные объявления (`archive=0`), Дата отправки просроченна, (`NOW()<discharge_date`)

Сделал только по первому пункту, но это просто.

```
SELECT 
            * ,DATE_FORMAT(shipping_date,'%d.%m.%Y')  as shipping_date, 
            DATE_FORMAT(discharge_date,'%d.%m.%Y')  as discharge_date1
        FROM 
            bid_country
        WHERE 
            id>=0 $string
        ORDER BY 
            date_create DESC
        $limit;
```

Переменные `$string` и `$limit` генерируются до этого. На них можно не обращать внимания, главное как отсортировать.

Comment: Не совсем ясно что вы хотите получить в результат. Есть некоторая путаница - вы говорите про условия выборки, но при этом хотите впихнуть их в сортировку. В принципе это возможно - но для лучшего понимания проблемы было бы хорошо если вы приведете упрощенный пример данных, которые у вас есть и то что вы хотите получить в результате. Можно это например сделать на http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Вам лучше использовать вложеный запрос и union http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350199/order-by-date-a-select-query-on-union-all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT * ,DATE_FORMAT(shipping_date,'%d.%m.%Y') as shipping_date,    
 DATE_FORMAT(discharge_date,'%d.%m.%Y') as discharge_date1
 FROM bid_country WHERE id>=0 AND discharge_date >= CURDATE()    
 ORDER BY date_create DESC, archive ASC
```